# Override value of object reference

Tags: javascript, reference, ecma

When you pass an object reference as an argument to a function, assigning to that reference merely changes what the reference is to but not the value, like so:

```
class meh {
    constructor() {
        this.obj = { member: 7 };
    }

    doSomething() {
        doFn(this.obj);
    }
    doFn(objRef) {
        objRef = { newMember: 4 } // Doesn't overwrite obj; merely assigns a new object to objRef.
    }
}
```

But is there a way to overwrite or otherwise assign a value to the actual location pointed by an object reference?  Meaning, is there a way to assign a new object to `objRef` (in `doFn`) and have it reflected in `obj`?

Comment: No, cause that would make the code unreliable. Changes could happen to variables from everywhere, even outside the scope which can lead to mysterious bugs. So no, this is impossible for good reasons.

Comment: Variables point at values, not the other way around. When you say `this.obj = foo`, this.obj points at `foo`'s location. When you subsequently say `this.obj = bar` your obj is now simply pointing at `bar`'s location now. Assignment doesn't change anything about the value. (Which is why `const` works the way it does, btw). It's also why variables don't have types in JS - only values do - variables simply point at a value and reassignment is just reassigning the pointer to the location of another value.

Answer (score -1):

It depends a bit on your situation.

In react as an example, you can store variables in a state, which there is a pre-built in function for updating, called this.setState, however if you're in pure javascript you can create your own store of global variables, and then update those directly. I don't suggest that, but as an example you can store the variables under window['somevariable'] to store them in the window object, these can later be accesses.

To make it even more fancy, you can create pre-built functions that does the job for you that you can just call, passing a parameter of the variable and the value to update as an object, and you mimic'ed the state characteristics of React.

Redux to give another example, has it neatly worked out with a centralized "Store" where you send data to and retrieve data from, check that out.

I hope it answers your question.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Reassigning a variable will never alter the original value. Period.

Comment: I am sorry, I am not saying that what he is asking is possible. I am giving him a solution how to do what he is trying to accomplish.

Comment: Fair enough. I would probably add that in your answer that modification via reassignment is not possible, however with something like Object.assign() or other similar concepts, you can modify/update the original object while keeping the reference the same. React is a **really** bad example, though, as immutability of state is a core concept, which is exactly what the OP doesn't want. The OP wants to mutate the original object with new/updated properties, but keep the object reference the same.

Comment: Feel free to edit your answer and I will be happy to upvote.